# Assistance with a complex MySQL SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I hope this is the appropriate forum to ask for assistance. I have an SQL Query (MySQL) that is not returning the correct records in a Date Range (between two dates). I am happy to answer questions in relation to the query, however if anyone can make suggestions or correct the SQL Query that would be an excellent learning exercise. Thank you.

```
$raw_query = sprintf("SELECT
swtickets.ticketid AS `Ticket ID`,
swtickettimetracks.tickettimetrackid AS `Track ID`,
swtickets.ticketmaskid AS `TicketMASK`,
(
    SELECT
        swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue
    FROM
        swcustomfieldvalues,
        swcustomfields
    WHERE
        swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldid = swcustomfields.customfieldid
    AND swtickets.ticketid = swcustomfieldvalues.typeid
    AND swcustomfields.title = 'Member Company'
    ORDER BY
        swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldvalueid DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS MemberCompany,
(
    SELECT
        swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue
    FROM
        swcustomfieldvalues,
        swcustomfields
    WHERE
        swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldid = swcustomfields.customfieldid
    AND swtickets.ticketid = swcustomfieldvalues.typeid
    AND swcustomfields.title = 'Member Name'
    ORDER BY
        swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldvalueid DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS MemberName,
(
    SELECT
        swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue
    FROM
        swcustomfieldvalues,
        swcustomfields
    WHERE
        swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldid = swcustomfields.customfieldid
    AND swtickets.ticketid = swcustomfieldvalues.typeid
    AND swcustomfields.title = 'Chargeable'
    AND 
        swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue = '40'
    ORDER BY
        swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldvalueid ASC
    LIMIT 1
) AS `Chg`,
swtickets.`subject` AS `Subject`,
swtickets.departmenttitle AS Category,
FROM_UNIXTIME(
    swtickettimetracks.workdateline
) AS `workDateline`,
FROM_UNIXTIME(
    swtickettimetracks.dateline
) AS `dateline`,
swtickettimetracks.timespent AS `Time Spent`,
swtickets.timeworked AS `Time Worked`
    FROM
swtickets
    INNER JOIN swusers ON swtickets.userid = swusers.userid
    INNER JOIN swuserorganizations ON swuserorganizations.userorganizationid = swusers.userorganizationid
    INNER JOIN swtickettimetracks ON swtickettimetracks.ticketid = swtickets.ticketid
    WHERE
    swuserorganizations.organizationname = '%s'
    AND (
    swtickets.ticketstatustitle = 'Closed'
OR swtickets.ticketstatustitle = 'Completed'
    )

    AND FROM_UNIXTIME(`workDateline`) >= '%s' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(`workDateline`) <= '%s'

    ORDER BY `Ticket ID`,`Track ID`",
        $userOrganization,
        $startDate,
        $endDate
    );
```

As I mentioned, the Query works - however it does not return the records correctly between the two dates.

However, IF I run this simple query against the database :

```
SELECT swtickettimetracks.tickettimetrackid, 
swtickettimetracks.ticketid, 
swtickettimetracks.dateline, 
swtickettimetracks.timespent, 
swtickettimetracks.timebillable,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(swtickettimetracks.workdateline)

    FROM swtickettimetracks

    WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(swtickettimetracks.workdateline) >= '2013-04-16' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(swtickettimetracks.workdateline) <= '2013-04-18'
```

I get the correct date range returned. Help? Thank you in anticipation.
Edward.

Comment: It's the correct forum but the question lacks one small detail.  You say that the php query does not return the expected results.  That kind of leaves us guessing as to the difference between what your expected and what you actually got.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to a) remove the non-SQL information, as your question is specifically about SQL, and b) remove the `tab` characters and replace with spaces (starting with an indent of 4 spaces for code block formatting) - you should never have tabs inside code blocks, as it interferes with the proper formatting. The more readable you make your question, the better your chances of getting an answer quickly. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are overthinking it, it's all in your different query WHERE clauses...

Your complex query returning the wrong results has

```
  (join conditions between other tables)
  AND swuserorganizations.organizationname = '%s'
  AND ( swtickets.ticketstatustitle = 'Closed'
     OR swtickets.ticketstatustitle = 'Completed' )
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(`workDateline`) >= '%s' 
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(`workDateline`) <= '%s'
```

Your Other query has

```
FROM swtickettimetracks
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(swtickettimetracks.workdateline) >= '2013-04-16' 
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(swtickettimetracks.workdateline) <= '2013-04-18'
```

So I would consider a few things.  The first where has

FROM_UNIXTIME >= '%s' and FROM_UNIXTIME <= '%s'

Are you sure the '%s' values are properly formatted to match the '2013-04-16' and '2013-04-18' format sample?

But more importantly, your first query is using the same date range (if correct), but is also only getting those for specific organization name AND (Closed or Completed) records.  So, if the second query is returning 100 records, but the main query only 70, then are the other 30 some status other than closed/completed, or a different organization?  In addition, if the join tables don't have matching IDs that would prevent those with invalid IDs from being returned.  The only way to confirm that is to change to LEFT-JOIN syntax on those tables and see the results.

Comment: Thank you @DRapp. Yes, the %s variables are 100% being passed in as YYYY-MM-DD, and next I will change to LEFT JOIN. And you advice on splitting the query into 2 to see if part 1 returns X records and how many are returned in part 2 to see if I'm dropping some records (if that makes sense). You advice and explanation has been most helpful. Thank you.